# grep -A with inverse match- print out only non-matching in the after field

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, text-formatting

I have a file that prints out multiple occurrences of '200 OK'. I am only interested in the last occurrence of '200 OK' that comes after the pattern 'COMMAND'. In my particular file, "COMMAND" prints 100 time. It would look like this:

```
otherdata
200 OK
otherdata 
200 OK
COMMAND
200 OK
```

So I use the command.

```
grep -A1 COMMAND file | grep -v '200 OK'
```

This give me the following output:

```
COMMAND xxxxx PASSWORD xxxxxx
--
COMMAND xxxxx PASSWORD xxxxxx
513 unknown user account
--
COMMAND xxxxxx PASSWORD xxxxxx
--
COMMAND xxxxxx PASSWORD xxxxxx
513 unknown user account
--
COMMAND xxxxxx PASSWORD xxxxxxx
--
```

I am getting everything other than the 200 OK, but I do not need the lines that contain

```
COMMAND xxxxx PASSWORD xxxxx
---
```

How can I get the output of only the lines with anything other than 200 OK and the line above it? Ideally, I want my output to include only lines like this and nothing else. The 513 is just an example there may be others.

```
COMMAND xxxxx PASSWORD xxxxxx
513 user account unknown
```

Comment: Could you please post a relevant input sample and expected output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/COMMAND/{N;/200/! p;}' file
```

This used `-n` to not print lines by default, then if a line matches `COMMAND`, join that line with the next line (`N` and if that does not match `200` print the combined lines.